# »Assistenten« oder »Assistent« im Akkusativ?

Tags: inflection, weak-declension

Satz:

> Es ist gut, einen Assistenten zu haben.

Ist der Satz so richtig, oder muss man *Assistent* statt *Assistenten* schreiben?

Comment: Akkusativ singular: den Assistenten. Siehe https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Assistent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Assistenten" ist richtiger, jedenfalls in der Schriftsprache. Assistent, wie auch andere Maskuline Wörter mit der Endung -ent, wird "schwach deklinert" d.h hat immer die Endung -en, wenn nicht in Nominativ Singularis. Hier steht Assistent in Akkusativ, daher die -en. Andere gewöhnliche Substantive, die der schwachen Deklination (oder n-Deklination) folgt, sind z.B. Löwe, Bär und Soltat.

Ergänzung, Danke an tofro: In der Umgangssprache wird aber die schwache Deklination oft einfach unterschlagen. Man sagt also meist "dem Soldat", "den Assistent". Die schwache Deklination gilt (zumindestens für den Singular) als "aussterbend"

Comment: Antwort ist richtig, allerdings sollte erwähnt werden, dass die n-Deklination in der Umgangssprache oft einfach unterschlagen wird: "dem Soldat", "den Assistent". Die n-Deklination gilt (zumindestens für den Singular) als "aussterbend"

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis. Werde ich in die Antwort einfügen :)

Comment: @tofro Sagt man also auch "dem Bär"?? Bin recht sicher ich habe umgangssprachlich "dem Bärn" gehört.

Comment: Ja, umgangssprachlich (aber mAn auf dem "Vormarsch" in die geschriebene Sprache) sagt man auch "dem Bär" oder "dem Junge"

Comment: Ihr wollt mir wohl einen Bär aufbinden!