# Nach »als«: Nominativ oder Dativ?

Tags: grammatical-case, conjunction

Steht im folgenden Satz *Dorfpolizist* im Nominativ oder im Dativ?

> Nominativ: Als *Dorfpolizist* war ihm ein so blutiger Fall nie
>   vorgekommen.

oder

> Dativ: Als *Dorfpolizisten* war ihm ein so blutiger Fall nie
>   vorgekommen.

Weche Variante ist richtig und weshalb?

Comment: Are you sure your first example is nominative?

Comment: Nein, ich bin nicht sicher. Aber wenn das erste Beispiel auch im Dativ stehen würde, dann wäre doch die Deklination von Dorfpolizist falsch. (En-Deklination)  - Egal, ob meine Angabe "Nominativ" im ersten Beispiel richtig ist oder falsch: Ich möchte einfach wissen, in welchen Fall man hier "Dorfpolizist" setzen muss.

Comment: Ich persönlich tendiere zu "Dativ", weil "Dorfpolizist" und "ihm" die gleiche Person bezeichnet und "ihm" ja im Dativ steht. -> gleiche Person: gleicher Fall. Andererseits habe ich das erste Beispiel, so wie es dasteht, gefunden. (Das stammt nicht von mir).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the adjective ending of accusative case is used in this sentence after »als«?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35442/why-is-the-adjective-ending-of-accusative-case-is-used-in-this-sentence-after-a)

Answer (score 1):

„Als Dorfpolizisten“, also im Dativ ist richtig.

Bei Vergleichswörtern wie „wie“ und „als“ müssen beide Seiten im gleichen Kasus stehen, auch wenn die Satzteile zwecks Betonung auseinandergerissen sind. Mit der normalen Wortstellung ist es vielleicht einfacher zu erkennen:

Ein so blutiger Fall war ihm als Dorfpolizisten nie vorgekommen.

Comment: Polizist muss wohl hier in Dativ stehen, aber in moderner Schreibweise muss man dies nicht mit der -en-Endung markieren, ist mir neulich beigebracht worden. http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31802/assistenten-oder-assistent-im-akkusativ/31803#31803   http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33853/warum-kriegt-z-b-student-die-endung-en-in-dem-casus-obliquus/33860#33860

Comment: @Beta Perhaps in colloquial or informal language (as pointed out by tofro in the comment to the post you are linking to), but not if the text is from a book or a newspaper.

Comment: Inzwischen habe ich noch folgendes gefnden: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Gebrauch/Satzteil.html
Kapitel "Ausnahmen und Sonderfälle: Nomen mit der Singularendung -en". Gemäss dieser Quelle soll die Endung auch weggelassen werden, wenn es nicht Umgangssprache ist.
Zitat: "Wenn ein Nomen der en/en-Klasse allein steht, wird es im Singular meist nicht gebeugt." ... und weiter ...
Zitat: "Immer mit Endung, wenn von einem gebeugten Wort begleitet" Beispiel: "Er stellte den Studenten als seinen Assistenten ein." 
Das entspricht exakt auch der Antwort von @guidot

Comment: Vielleicht ist es regional bedingt oder einfach auch Geschmackssache, aber mir kommt es wirklich komisch und falsch vor, die schwache Deklination hier wegzulassen.

Answer (score 1):

Wie man beim Ersetzen von *Dorfpolizist* durch *Polizeibeamter* feststellt, ist der Dativ hier korrekt.

Als Berufsbezeichnung ist hier der *Nullartikel* anzuwenden; die Endung *-en* hätte damit den Nachteil, bei Unterscheidung Singular/Plural nicht mehr zu unterstützen.

Will man also nicht zu einer empfehlenswerten Umformulierung greifen, wie

> Seit er Dorfpolizist war, ...

ist das Weglassen des *-en* eine nahe liegende Lösung.

Auch das Einfügen eines Adjektivs könnte helfen, wobei sich das -en fast aufdrängt:

> Als erfahrenem Dorfpolizisten...

Comment: Mir ist nicht klar, wie man durch Ersetzen von Dorfpolizist durch Polizeibeamter harausfinden kann, dass der Dativ korrekt ist.
-> der Polizist, den Polizisten, dem Polizisten, des Polizisten / 
-> der Beamte, den Beamten, dem Beamten, des Beamten
-> Die Deklination der beiden Nomen funktioniert doch gleich (?)

Comment: @Wogehu Es **muss** dann m. E. *Polizeibeamten* heißen, die Nominativ-Form ist hier offensichtlicher falsch, es liegt schon an dem Effekt der "verschluckten" Dativ-Endung von *Polizist*.

Answer (score 1):

Substantives derived from Greek words like

- Student
- Polizist
- Ministrant

tend to have an -en added for the genitive, dative and accusative case.

Modern, especially colloquial German accepts these cases, however, in the nominative form.

The case in your example is actually *dative*, because the apposition must follow the case of the  associated substantive ("ihm"), which is dative as well. Text-book-grammar-correct German would say *Polizisten* for dative, but modern German accepts the dative form of *Polizist* as well.